# how to regularly update file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code in python that reads a very huge file fetches data from another file and writes into a new file with the matched and not matched values.
say for eg

file 1:
ab
bc
cd
gh

file 2:
ab catch1
ab catch2
bc catch1
bc catch3
bc catch4
ef catch1

output :
ab
  catch1
  catch2
bc
  catch1
  catch3
cd
gh

The issue is the output file doesn't get updated regularly, so I cannot monitor how much of the content from file 1 have been processed. 
I need to monitor the output regularly as the input files are very large and I cannot approximate the time it will take to complete.

Comment: Seems like a good time for you to learn about databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "flush()" method of file object

The flush method forces the data in memory to be written to a file before it is written to the file.

use like this

```
output.flush()
```

example Code A:

```
a = open('test', 'w')

a.write('good2')

b = open('test', 'r')

print b.read()

a.close()
b.close()
```

example Code B:

```
a = open('test', 'w')

a.write('good2')
a.flush()
b = open('test', 'r')

print b.read()

a.close()
b.close()
```

Examples A and B will behave differently.

flush method will be helpful to check the current status of file which being written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use progress bar in python script:

```
import time
import progressbar

maxval = 100
pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=maxval)
pbar.start()
for i in range(maxval):
    # do something
    time.sleep(0.05)
    pbar.update(i+1)
pbar.finish()
```

or for checking content of output file you need to reload it again and again display newly written data.

Comment: Thanks for this, At the moment my work is done with the flush function. But will definitely give this a try after some days.